# How to change listpicker dropdown ItemTemplate background?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, listpicker

I have a Windows Phone 8 listpicker that I'm trying to change the background color of, however, it only seems to change the item background and not the dropdown box background as you can see in the screen capture. The dropdown box seems to be binded to the WP8 theme. How can I change the background of the entire dropdown box and not just each individual item?

[image: Listpicker.ItemTemplate]

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="BackgroundListPicker" Background="Black" ItemsSource="{Binding BackgroundsList}">
<toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate >
    <DataTemplate x:Name="BackgroundItemTemplate"  >
       <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0">
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <Image  Source="{Binding BackgroundThumb}" Width="30" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding BackgroundName}" Foreground="White"  Margin="12,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
         </StackPanel>
       </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
  </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
 </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Comment: Setting a hardset height/width of 30px on a StackPanel in an ItemTemplate, you would expect that result. Have you tried setting the background of the actual control?

Comment: Please explain where I set a hardset 30px width/height on the StackPanel itself. I set an image to 30px width/height but that is it. I have tried setting everything to black, the white background just doesn't want to change.

Comment: Yea I worded it wrong, don't fixate on the StackPanel, the point is you have an image in an item template so of course it's not going to apply to the whole control. If you look at the list picker style template then somewhere in there should be a Border or something with its Background bound to the template like `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"` which just wants a brush, and since I don't recall exactly if WP supports ImageBrush, you may just have to rig in your own spot to feed it an image in the template.

Comment: Where might I find a ListPicker ControlTemplate to modify? It isnt in the project source and Googling it just keeps revealing WP7 control templates which are out of date.

Comment: Right click it either on the design screen or the in the object tree on the document outline panel and select "Edit Template->Edit A Copy" and it will pull out the style template(s) needed and either add them to your view or a resource dictionary if you choose.

Comment: @ChrisW. Can you add your reply as the answer so I can mark it correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your issue was that you were attempting to apply an image to an item. When you needed to hit the control itself that the items populate via `ItemsPresenter` so by pulling out the default style template for the control, and either making a place to pass in your image for an instance, or placing one directly into the template itself. You get your resulting background image for the ListPicker background to fall behind the items populating it.

Glad you found your remedy! Cheers.